# I'm on minecraft bedrock and I lost my hotbar and crosshair

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm on minecraft bedrock and I lost my hotbar and crosshair. I know how to press F1 but that doesn't work on bedrock. Please help

Comment: Just google how to toggle HUD on minecraft bedrock.
You should very quickly find an answer

Answer (score 1):

There's a "Hide HUD" option. Tap/click the pause button (or where the pause button should be if it's hidden), go to settings, and turn off that option.

Answer (score 0):

This happens pretty often when playing a world with behaviour or resource packs. When it happens, the easiest way to fix it is to save and quit (assuming you can remember where the buttons are, since they disappear). Alternatively, you can just close the game and reopen it, though this may lose some progress since the last autosave.